# Linux Parsing Output and Combine Lines

Tags: regex, linux, parsing, awk, sed

I have the following output (in linux):

```
wwn = 5001248018b6d7af  
node_wwn = 5001248018b6d7ae  
wwn = 5001248118b6d7af  
node_wwn = 5001248118b6d7ae
```

I need to parse the output so it will looks like that:

```
50:01:24:80:18:b6:d7:ae:50:01:24:80:18:b6:d7:af
50:01:24:81:18:b6:d7:ae:50:01:24:81:18:b6:d7:af
```

the output is the node_wwn and its wwn.

I done this job using some C# app but its too complicated to take the output and past it to the program.

```
string command = "cat /proc/sll/info |grep -B 9 up| grep wwn";
        string temp;
        string []commandOutput;
        string[] wwns;
        string[] wwpns;

        hbaList = new List<HBA>();

        commandOutput = (exec.RunCommand(command)).Trim().Split('\n');

        wwns = Array.FindAll(commandOutput, item => item.StartsWith("wwn = "));
        wwpns = Array.FindAll(commandOutput, item => item.StartsWith("node_wwn = "));

        for (int i =0; i<wwns.Length;i++)
        {
            hba = new HBA();

            temp = string.Format("{1}", (wwpns[i].Split('='))).Trim();
            temp += string.Format("{1}", (wwns[i].Split('='))).Trim();
            temp = Regex.Replace(temp, ".{2}", "$0:");
            temp = temp.Remove(temp.Length - 1);
            hba.ID = temp;
            hbaList.Add(hba);
        }
```

Please help...

Thanks Almog

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: Posted thanks,,, I not familiar with linux parsing commands like sed and awk...help please

Comment: Why do you use `grep -B9`? What other output is there which you are not showing us? The entire task can easily be handled by a single Awk script but we need to understand the expected input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code writing service, hello :)

I did it with GNU awk.

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f

function out_wwn(wwn, node_wwn) {
    out = sprintf("%s%s", node_wwn, wwn);
    patsplit(out, a, "[0-9a-f]{2}");
    for (i = 1; i <= length(a); i++) {
        if (i > 1) printf(":");
        printf("%s", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/^wwn/ {wwn=$3}
/^node_wwn/ {out_wwn(wwn, $3)}
```

Usage in your case:

```
cat /proc/sll/info |grep -B 9 up| awk -f [the file above]
```

Maybe you can also remove the first `grep`, depending on your input. In that case you need just do:

```
awk -f [the file above] < /proc/sll/info
```

Comment: @almog50 thank me with upvote and validation instead ;)

Comment: The `cat` and, as you note, probably the `grep` too are [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html).

Answer (score 1):

Guessing a bit here...

```
awk '$1 == "wwn" { result = $3; next }
  $1 == "node_wwn" { result = $3 result; next }
   /up/ { for(i=1, sep = ""; i<length(result); sep = ":", i += 2)
        printf("%s%s", sep, substr(result, i, 2));
      printf "\n" }' /proc/sll/info
```

Assuming the `wwn` will always precede the `node_wwn` and be followed by `up` before the next output record, and that whitespace patterns are consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a perl version

```
while (<>) {
  if ($_ =~ /(node_)*wwn\s*=\s*(\S+)/) {
      $node = "$2$node";
      if($1 eq "node_") {
          $node =~ s/(..)(?!$)/\1:/g;
          print "$node\n";
          $node = "";
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -r 'N;s/.* = (\S+).* = (\S+).*/\2\1/;s/..\B/&:/g' file
```

This reads two lines at time, removes the cruft and re-arranges the data then inserts a `:` between each two characters followed by a non-word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing out another option.

This assumes node_wwn line directly follows the wwn line..

```
$ cat file
wwn = 5001248018b6d7af
node_wwn = 5001248018b6d7ae
wwn = 5001248118b6d7af
node_wwn = 5001248118b6d7ae

$ awk '$1=="wwn"{nf=$NF;getline;print $NF""nf}' file | perl -pe 's/\w{2}\B/$&:/g'
50:01:24:80:18:b6:d7:ae:50:01:24:80:18:b6:d7:af
50:01:24:81:18:b6:d7:ae:50:01:24:81:18:b6:d7:af
```